# How can I have UITableViewCells with rounded corners?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, calendar

My app has a ManagedObject that has different types of fields
So, I want it for the user to edit each one and also have it display different info for each.

If you look at the Calendar app, when you Add an Event, you'll notice Title/Location in one cell, Starts/Ends in another, Repeat... so on.

So... in Interface Builder I have all my UITableViewCells but they are all squared. Not with neatly rounded corners.

Is this done with IB and I'm missing a setting? Are they all different views amassed in one place?
I know I will have to custom code each one. I just want the rounded corners first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rounded `UITableViewCells`, change the style of your `UITableView` from "Plain" to "Grouped". This can be done in Interface Builder. Then, since it's actually the edges of each *section* that get rounded, put each cell in its own section.

Comment: But I don't have my UITableViewCells inside a UITableView. They are all on their own...

Comment: I've never seen that done before. I suggest putting your table view cells inside a table. Check out Apple's Table View Programming Guide for more information.

Comment: Check out the Calendar app in the iPhone.  You'll see the example I'm talking about. (halfway through the Guide now)

Comment: What makes you think they're not in a table?

Comment: Got it working. Didn't understand you at first, but your method worked!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working. What extra information would have helped you? If you add it in a comment, you can help others who are in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I made a subview of UITableViewCell and put all my controls in there. If you do that, then you'll see the corners cut. After dragging everything on the content view, the problem was solved.